# Passing user object to view doesnt work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

When passing a user object to my view, I cant seem to access its profile properties. Its showing me an empty value in my textbox in my view.

**Model:**

```
...
public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
...
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfile()
    {
        EditProfileViewModel model = new EditProfileViewModel();
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var currentUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        model.user = currentUser;

        return View(model);
    }
```

**View:**

```
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @value = Model.user.FirstName, @class = "form-control" })
...
```

---

I can fix the problem by simply setting properties in my controller and passing those properties to my view, but that would require me to write more code in my controller if I have tons of properties.

**Controller Example:** *(Assuming I have a correct model for it)*

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfile()
    {
        EditProfileViewModel model = new EditProfileViewModel();
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var currentUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        model.FirstName = currentUser.FirstName;
        model.LastNameName = currentUser.LastName;
        model.StreetName = currentUser.StreetName;
        ...

        return View(model);
    }
```

---

Another solution would be to access the currentUser directly from within the view, but I prefer to keep my view as clean as possible.

**Example View:**

```
@{
   var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
   var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}
```

---

**So my question is:**
how can I pass a user object and access it from within my view, like I showed at the top of my question, specifically the '@value' part? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: The whole point of `TextBoxFor` is for razor to set the value for you so why are you also trying to use `@value`? I suspect `m.FirstName` is taking precedence and of course there is no `FirstName` property on the model. Try `m.user.FirstName` and remove the `@value` attribute.

Comment: m.user.FirstName solved the problem, ty! I didnt know @value was unnecessary here. Thanks for clearing that up :)